# Is it possible to get the screen/monitor name where a specific application is displayed on?

Tags: x11, xrandr, xdotool

I would like to find out what screen/monitor (not desktop) a GUI application is displayed on.

For example: my mail client is running on my third desktop, which is displayed on my second monitor ("DP-1-3"). So, my mail client is displayed on "DP-1-3".

I have tried using `xdotool selectwindow get_desktop_for_window`, but this returns the virtual desktop number/id, not the actual screen/monitor. Preferably, I would like to see the name of the screen/monitor as they are displayed in `xrandr`.

Thank you!

Comment: **Somewhere** you have configured your third desktop to be displayed on your second monitor (probably in your Window Manager (WM)), and that's where you need to get this information (if it's not static). This is WM dependent, and there are no standard tools for that.

Comment: @dirkt At the moment I use i3WM. But as far as I can tell, there is no way of finding out what screen a virtual desktop is displayed on. If my understanding is correct, this should be managed by X11, not just my WM. My goal is a solution that works for any WM under X11, not just the one I use right now

Comment: Assuming you have Xinerama, and the different screens share a framebuffer (anything else needs your own `xorg.conf`, but check your `/var/log/Xorg.log`), it's solely the task of the WM to place windows (and therefore indirectly put them on screens). Some (but not all) WMs follow the EWMH/NetWM specification, and in that case you can use e.g. `wmctrl` to find some things out. So you need to walk the whole abstraction chain yourself to figure out the xrandr output name.

Answer (score 1):

After some help from @dirkt (thank you so much!), I was able to figure it out. It is not the prettiest solution, but the following works for me:

1. Fetch the desktop the application is running on by using `wmctrl -l`.
2. Find the offset of this desktop by using `wmctrl -d`.
3. Compare this offset to that of the active monitors via `xrandr --listactivemonitors`

Using `awk` I am able to find the exact content I need, and pass it around. If someone has a better solution, please do let me know! For now, I will use this.